# How to access certain items from a python requests response?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to python requests and I am unsure how to access one singular item from the response rather than all of them. Any help would be appreciated. I would like to be able to print the kdRatio, there is multiple different kdRatios in the response but I was looking for the one following lifetime and  All and Properties. Thanks

```
import requests as rq

header = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "call-of-duty-modern-warfare.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "0beff1d7acmsh29065741543208dp152ecbjsnb56e8654cc77"
    }


response = rq.get('https://call-of-duty-modern- 
warfare.p.rapidapi.com/multiplayer/%25C7%259Ep%25C3%25ABx%25231878/battle', headers=header)

print(response)

print(response.text)
```

Here is the response I am getting.

<Response [200]>
{"title":"mw","platform":"battle","username":"Ǟpëx#1878","type":"mp","level":55,"maxLevel":0,"levelXpRemainder":3000,"levelXpGained":7000,"prestige":0,"prestigeId":0,"maxPrestige":0,"totalXp":960000,"paragonRank":0,"paragonId":0,"s":1,"p":1,"lifetime":{"all":{"properties":{"recordLongestWinStreak":14,"recordXpInAMatch":29276,"accuracy":0.2253633737564087,"losses":456,"totalGamesPlayed":1216,"score":2853122,"winLossRatio":1.094298243522644,"totalShots":286484,"bestScoreXp":0,"gamesPlayed":1216,"bestSquardKills":0,"bestSguardWave":0,"bestConfirmed":19,"deaths":13057,"wins":499,"bestSquardCrates":0,"kdRatio":1.495213270187378,"bestAssists":27,"bestFieldgoals":0,"bestScore":16625,"recordDeathsInAMatch":55,"scorePerGame":2346.3174342105262,"bestSPM":2450,"bestKillChains":0,"recordKillsInAMatch":113,"suicides":79,"wlRatio":1.094298243522644,"currentWinStreak":2,"bestMatchBonusXp":0,"bestMatchXp":0,"bestSguardWeaponLevel":0,"bestKD":16,"kills":19523,"bestKillsAsInfected":3,"bestReturns":0,"bestStabs":0,"bestKillsAsSurvivor":10,"timePlayedTotal":488334,"bestDestructions":1,"headshots":3303,"bestRescues":5,"assists":3237,"ties":1,"recordKillStreak":29,"bestPlants":1,"misses":221921,"bestDamage":0,"bestSetbacks":0,"bestTouchdowns":0,"scorePerMinute":350.5537603361634,"bestDeaths":55,"bestMedalXp":0,"bestDefends":41,"bestSquardRevives":0,"bestKills":113,"bestDefuses":0,"bestCaptures":8,"hits":64563,"bestKillStreak":29,"bestDenied":8}},"mode":{"gun":{"properties":{"kills":12,"score":1262,"timePlayed":311,"kdRatio":0.9230769230769231,"setBacks":0,"scorePerMinute":243.47266881028938,"stabs":0,"deaths":13}},"dom":{"properties":{"kills":3986,"score":466680,"timePlayed":92224,"kdRatio":1.619008935824533,"captures":228,"defends":412,"scorePerMinute":303.617279666898,"deaths":2462}},"war":{"properties":{"kills":1292,"score":165815,"timePlayed":25846,"kdRatio":1.453318335208099,"assists":271,"scorePerMinute":384.92996982124896,"deaths":889}},"hq":{"properties":{"kills":4111,"score":441585,"timePlayed":99696,"kdRatio":1.6563255439161966,"captures":93,"defends":27,"scorePerMinute":265.7589070775157,"deaths":2482}},"hc_dom":{"properties":{"kills":942,"score":103870,"timePlayed":23342,"kdRatio":1.3792093704245973,"captures":46,"defends":81,"scorePerMinute":266.9951160997344,"deaths":683}},"hc_conf":{"properties":{"kills":73,"score":8300,"timePlayed":1367,"kdRatio":1.2372881355932204,"confirms":15,"scorePerMinute":364.3013899049012,"denies":20,"deaths":59}},"koth":{"properties":{"kills":1311,"score":187420,"timePlayed":27342,"kdRatio":1.4219088937093276,"defends":37,"objTime":697,"scorePerMinute":411.27935044985736,"deaths":922}},"conf":{"properties":{"kills":1042,"score":146180,"timePlayed":19643,"kdRatio":1.507959479015919,"confirms":273,"scorePerMinute":446.5102071984931,"denies":104,"deaths":691}},"hc_hq":{"properties":{"kills":166,"score":17735,"timePlayed":2726,"kdRatio":1.2296296296296296,"captures":2,"defends":1,"scorePerMinute":390.35216434336024,"deaths":135}},"arena":{"properties":{"kills":815,"score":143855,"timePlayed":41493,"damage":97577,"kdRatio":1.1256906077348066,"assists":193,"scorePerMinute":208.0182199407129,"deaths":724}},"br_dmz":{"properties":{"wins":0,"kills":7,"kdRatio":3.5,"downs":9,"topTwentyFive":0,"topTen":0,"contracts":0,"revives":0,"topFive":0,"score":3312,"timePlayed":1108,"gamesPlayed":1,"tokens":0,"scorePerMinute":179.35018050541518,"cash":0,"deaths":2}},"br":{"properties":{"wins":5,"kills":736,"kdRatio":1.6919540229885057,"downs":789,"topTwentyFive":117,"topTen":54,"contracts":104,"revives":100,"topFive":27,"score":713500,"timePlayed":169249,"gamesPlayed":146,"tokens":0,"scorePerMinute":252.94093318128913,"cash":0,"deaths":435}},"sd":{"properties":{"kills":146,"score":71070,"timePlayed":44172,"kdRatio":1.4174757281553398,"plants":0,"scorePerMinute":96.5362673186634,"defuses":2,"deaths":103}},"grnd":{"properties":{"kills":0,"score":1875,"timePlayed":292,"kdRatio":0,"defends":0,"objTime":0,"scorePerMinute":385.2739726027398,"deaths":0}},"cyber":{"properties":{"kills":70,"score":37335,"timePlayed":20866,"kdRatio":1.206896551724138,"plants":1,"scorePerMinute":107.35646506278157,"revives":0,"deaths":58}},"hc_war":{"properties":{"kills":0,"score":625,"timePlayed":222,"kdRatio":0,"assists":0,"scorePerMinute":168.9189189189189,"deaths":0}},"br_all":{"properties":{"wins":5,"kills":743,"kdRatio":1.700228832951945,"downs":798,"topTwentyFive":117,"topTen":54,"contracts":104,"revives":100,"topFive":27,"score":716812,"timePlayed":170357,"gamesPlayed":147,"tokens":0,"scorePerMinute":252.46229975874195,"cash":0,"deaths":437}},"hc_sd":{"properties":{"kills":0,"score":0,"timePlayed":0,"kdRatio":0,"plants":0,"scorePerMinute":0,"defuses":0,"deaths":0}},"arm":{"properties":{"kills":526,"score":76725,"timePlayed":25625,"kdRatio":1.1311827956989247,"captures":27,"defends":16,"scorePerMinute":179.64878048780488,"deaths":465}},"hc_cyber":{"properties":{"kills":0,"score":0,"timePlayed":0,"kdRatio":0,"plants":0,"scorePerMinute":0,"revives":0,"deaths":0}},"infect":{"properties":{"kills":67,"score":28425,"infected":17,"timePlayed":4649,"kdRatio":0.9305555555555556,"scorePerMinute":366.85308668530865,"time":2641,"deaths":72}}},"map":{},"itemData":{"weapon_assault_rifle":{"iw8_ar_tango21":{"properties":{"hits":41,"kills":8,"kdRatio":8,"headshots":1,"accuracy":0.16141732283464566,"shots":254,"deaths":0}},"iw8_ar_mike4":{"properties":{"hits":11685,"kills":2576,"kdRatio":1.4015233949945594,"headshots":471,"accuracy":0.2240136497833672,"shots":52162,"deaths":1838}},"iw8_ar_valpha":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_ar_falpha":{"properties":{"hits":54,"kills":14,"kdRatio":1.5555555555555556,"headshots":5,"accuracy":0.18305084745762712,"shots":295,"deaths":9}},"iw8_ar_mcharlie":{"properties":{"hits":870,"kills":141,"kdRatio":1.3689320388349515,"headshots":35,"accuracy":0.223305954825462,"shots":3896,"deaths":103}},"iw8_ar_akilo47":{"properties":{"hits":3741,"kills":781,"kdRatio":1.3259762308998302,"headshots":137,"accuracy":0.26047904191616766,"shots":14362,"deaths":589}},"iw8_ar_asierra12":{"properties":{"hits":456,"kills":151,"kdRatio":1.26890756302521,"headshots":33,"accuracy":0.22233057045343735,"shots":2051,"deaths":119}},"iw8_ar_galima":{"properties":{"hits":3,"kills":1,"kdRatio":1,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.23076923076923078,"shots":13,"deaths":0}},"iw8_ar_sierra552":{"properties":{"hits":1611,"kills":353,"kdRatio":1.6045454545454545,"headshots":48,"accuracy":0.23719081272084805,"shots":6792,"deaths":220}},"iw8_ar_falima":{"properties":{"hits":2579,"kills":1010,"kdRatio":1.6476345840130506,"headshots":208,"accuracy":0.26316326530612244,"shots":9800,"deaths":613}},"iw8_ar_anovember94":{"properties":{"hits":24,"kills":4,"kdRatio":0.8,"headshots":3,"accuracy":0.13114754098360656,"shots":183,"deaths":5}},"iw8_ar_kilo433":{"properties":{"hits":5034,"kills":1034,"kdRatio":1.267156862745098,"headshots":179,"accuracy":0.2387818992505455,"shots":21082,"deaths":816}},"iw8_ar_scharlie":{"properties":{"hits":326,"kills":91,"kdRatio":1.3582089552238805,"headshots":12,"accuracy":0.24847560975609756,"shots":1312,"deaths":67}}},"weapon_shotgun":{"iw8_sh_mike26":{"properties":{"hits":5,"kills":1,"kdRatio":1,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.3125,"shots":16,"deaths":0}},"iw8_sh_charlie725":{"properties":{"hits":1538,"kills":1195,"kdRatio":1.3307349665924275,"headshots":187,"accuracy":0.694043321299639,"shots":2216,"deaths":898}},"iw8_sh_oscar12":{"properties":{"hits":973,"kills":441,"kdRatio":1.1221374045801527,"headshots":45,"accuracy":0.43053097345132746,"shots":2260,"deaths":393}},"iw8_sh_romeo870":{"properties":{"hits":58,"kills":28,"kdRatio":0.8,"headshots":4,"accuracy":0.5272727272727272,"shots":110,"deaths":35}},"iw8_sh_dpapa12":{"properties":{"hits":20,"kills":9,"kdRatio":0.6428571428571429,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.32786885245901637,"shots":61,"deaths":14}}},"weapon_marksman":{"iw8_sn_sbeta":{"properties":{"hits":192,"kills":143,"kdRatio":0.9930555555555556,"headshots":35,"accuracy":0.3742690058479532,"shots":513,"deaths":144}},"iw8_sn_crossbow":{"properties":{"hits":4,"kills":7,"kdRatio":1.4,"headshots":2,"accuracy":0.125,"shots":32,"deaths":5}},"iw8_sn_kilo98":{"properties":{"hits":76,"kills":70,"kdRatio":1.1666666666666667,"headshots":32,"accuracy":0.4342857142857143,"shots":175,"deaths":60}},"iw8_sn_mike14":{"properties":{"hits":52,"kills":27,"kdRatio":1.9285714285714286,"headshots":12,"accuracy":0.23318385650224216,"shots":223,"deaths":14}},"iw8_sn_sksierra":{"properties":{"hits":26,"kills":9,"kdRatio":9,"headshots":5,"accuracy":0.2857142857142857,"shots":91,"deaths":0}}},"weapon_sniper":{"iw8_sn_romeo700":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_sn_alpha50":{"properties":{"hits":138,"kills":168,"kdRatio":1.3658536585365855,"headshots":41,"accuracy":0.36507936507936506,"shots":378,"deaths":123}},"iw8_sn_hdromeo":{"properties":{"hits":22,"kills":27,"kdRatio":0.8181818181818182,"headshots":5,"accuracy":0.3188405797101449,"shots":69,"deaths":33}},"iw8_sn_delta":{"properties":{"hits":79,"kills":51,"kdRatio":1,"headshots":15,"accuracy":0.30268199233716475,"shots":261,"deaths":51}},"iw8_sn_xmike109":{"properties":{"hits":1,"kills":1,"kdRatio":1,"headshots":0,"accuracy":1,"shots":1,"deaths":0}}},"tacticals":{"equip_gas_grenade":{"properties":{"extraStat1":1,"uses":19}},"equip_snapshot_grenade":{"properties":{"extraStat1":471,"uses":979}},"equip_decoy":{"properties":{"extraStat1":95,"uses":15}},"equip_smoke":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":157}},"equip_concussion":{"properties":{"extraStat1":280,"uses":660}},"equip_hb_sensor":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":98}},"equip_flash":{"properties":{"extraStat1":101,"uses":283}},"equip_adrenaline":{"properties":{"extraStat1":142214,"uses":2505}}},"lethals":{"equip_frag":{"properties":{"kills":41,"uses":556}},"equip_thermite":{"properties":{"kills":2,"uses":25}},"equip_semtex":{"properties":{"kills":6,"uses":71}},"equip_claymore":{"properties":{"kills":225,"uses":1509}},"equip_c4":{"properties":{"kills":57,"uses":664}},"equip_at_mine":{"properties":{"kills":285,"uses":2563}},"equip_throwing_knife":{"properties":{"kills":5,"uses":30}},"equip_molotov":{"properties":{"kills":24,"uses":465}}},"weapon_lmg":{"iw8_lm_kilo121":{"properties":{"hits":218,"kills":59,"kdRatio":1.5128205128205128,"headshots":13,"accuracy":0.15900802334062727,"shots":1371,"deaths":39}},"iw8_lm_mkilo3":{"properties":{"hits":441,"kills":105,"kdRatio":1.09375,"headshots":18,"accuracy":0.17904993909866018,"shots":2463,"deaths":96}},"iw8_lm_mgolf34":{"properties":{"hits":64,"kills":20,"kdRatio":1.8181818181818181,"headshots":6,"accuracy":0.17344173441734417,"shots":369,"deaths":11}},"iw8_lm_lima86":{"properties":{"hits":150,"kills":25,"kdRatio":1.25,"headshots":8,"accuracy":0.20080321285140562,"shots":747,"deaths":20}},"iw8_lm_pkilo":{"properties":{"hits":1390,"kills":342,"kdRatio":1.1324503311258278,"headshots":62,"accuracy":0.15873015873015872,"shots":8757,"deaths":302}},"iw8_lm_sierrax":{"properties":{"hits":1875,"kills":429,"kdRatio":1.1230366492146597,"headshots":63,"accuracy":0.22278992395437264,"shots":8416,"deaths":382}},"iw8_lm_mgolf36":{"properties":{"hits":1756,"kills":388,"kdRatio":1.065934065934066,"headshots":88,"accuracy":0.20223425083496488,"shots":8683,"deaths":364}}},"weapon_launcher":{"iw8_la_gromeo":{"properties":{"hits":23,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.45098039215686275,"shots":51,"deaths":26}},"iw8_la_rpapa7":{"properties":{"hits":3,"kills":51,"kdRatio":1.1590909090909092,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.02040816326530612,"shots":147,"deaths":44}},"iw8_la_juliet":{"properties":{"hits":8,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0.24242424242424243,"shots":33,"deaths":0}},"iw8_la_kgolf":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_la_mike32":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":14,"deaths":0}}},"supers":{"super_emp_drone":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":0}},"super_trophy":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":33,"misc2":0,"uses":32}},"super_ammo_drop":{"properties":{"kills":1,"misc1":207,"misc2":0,"uses":108}},"super_weapon_drop":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":2,"misc2":0,"uses":1}},"super_fulton":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":0}},"super_armor_drop":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":24}},"super_select":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":303}},"super_tac_insert":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":2,"misc2":0,"uses":2}},"super_recon_drone":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":5,"misc2":0,"uses":5}},"super_deadsilence":{"properties":{"kills":616,"misc1":9,"misc2":0,"uses":474}},"super_supply_drop":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":45}},"super_tac_cover":{"properties":{"kills":0,"misc1":807,"misc2":0,"uses":33}},"super_support_box":{"properties":{"kills":29,"misc1":0,"misc2":0,"uses":34}}},"weapon_pistol":{"iw8_pi_cpapa":{"properties":{"hits":91,"kills":50,"kdRatio":0.7142857142857143,"headshots":11,"accuracy":0.20634920634920634,"shots":441,"deaths":70}},"iw8_pi_mike9":{"properties":{"hits":12,"kills":3,"kdRatio":3,"headshots":1,"accuracy":0.11764705882352941,"shots":102,"deaths":0}},"iw8_pi_mike1911":{"properties":{"hits":91,"kills":18,"kdRatio":0.8571428571428571,"headshots":2,"accuracy":0.1961206896551724,"shots":464,"deaths":21}},"iw8_pi_golf21":{"properties":{"hits":219,"kills":26,"kdRatio":1.1818181818181819,"headshots":4,"accuracy":0.26290516206482595,"shots":833,"deaths":22}},"iw8_pi_decho":{"properties":{"hits":203,"kills":73,"kdRatio":0.7019230769230769,"headshots":15,"accuracy":0.3481989708404803,"shots":583,"deaths":104}},"iw8_pi_papa320":{"properties":{"hits":87,"kills":16,"kdRatio":0.4444444444444444,"headshots":5,"accuracy":0.17864476386036962,"shots":487,"deaths":36}}},"weapon_other":{"iw8_me_riotshield":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":2,"kdRatio":0.5,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":4}}},"weapon_smg":{"iw8_sm_mpapa7":{"properties":{"hits":5392,"kills":944,"kdRatio":1.3964497041420119,"headshots":194,"accuracy":0.255315119087078,"shots":21119,"deaths":676}},"iw8_sm_augolf":{"properties":{"hits":6903,"kills":1747,"kdRatio":1.373427672955975,"headshots":290,"accuracy":0.23947131062235483,"shots":28826,"deaths":1272}},"iw8_sm_papa90":{"properties":{"hits":3969,"kills":746,"kdRatio":1.231023102310231,"headshots":180,"accuracy":0.22036533229692964,"shots":18011,"deaths":606}},"iw8_sm_charlie9":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_sm_mpapa5":{"properties":{"hits":6885,"kills":1647,"kdRatio":1.5082417582417582,"headshots":283,"accuracy":0.22102728731942214,"shots":31150,"deaths":1092}},"iw8_sm_smgolf45":{"properties":{"hits":24,"kills":5,"kdRatio":5,"headshots":1,"accuracy":0.23300970873786409,"shots":103,"deaths":0}},"iw8_sm_beta":{"properties":{"hits":3053,"kills":686,"kdRatio":1.4503171247357294,"headshots":126,"accuracy":0.2310253499810821,"shots":13215,"deaths":473}},"iw8_sm_victor":{"properties":{"hits":61,"kills":11,"kdRatio":0.6111111111111112,"headshots":2,"accuracy":0.23371647509578544,"shots":261,"deaths":18}},"iw8_sm_uzulu":{"properties":{"hits":3345,"kills":989,"kdRatio":1.356652949245542,"headshots":184,"accuracy":0.21162849550803492,"shots":15806,"deaths":729}}},"weapon_melee":{"iw8_me_akimboblunt":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_me_akimboblades":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":0,"kdRatio":0,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":0}},"iw8_knife":{"properties":{"hits":0,"kills":9,"kdRatio":0.17307692307692307,"headshots":0,"accuracy":0,"shots":0,"deaths":52}}}},"scorestreakData":{"lethalScorestreakData":{"precision_airstrike":{"properties":{"extraStat1":92,"uses":110,"awardedCount":96}},"cruise_predator":{"properties":{"extraStat1":13,"uses":12,"awardedCount":0}},"manual_turret":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":3,"awardedCount":0}},"white_phosphorus":{"properties":{"extraStat1":3,"uses":1,"awardedCount":1}},"hover_jet":{"properties":{"extraStat1":482,"uses":176,"awardedCount":177}},"chopper_gunner":{"properties":{"extraStat1":507,"uses":72,"awardedCount":77}},"gunship":{"properties":{"extraStat1":19,"uses":3,"awardedCount":3}},"sentry_gun":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":7,"awardedCount":4}},"toma_strike":{"properties":{"extraStat1":17,"uses":39,"awardedCount":25}},"nuke":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":0,"awardedCount":0}},"juggernaut":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":0,"awardedCount":0}},"pac_sentry":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":0,"awardedCount":0}},"chopper_support":{"properties":{"extraStat1":2,"uses":1,"awardedCount":1}},"bradley":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":0,"awardedCount":0}}},"supportScorestreakData":{"airdrop":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":48,"awardedCount":55}},"radar_drone_overwatch":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":66,"awardedCount":64}},"scrambler_drone_guard":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":5,"awardedCount":0}},"uav":{"properties":{"extraStat1":5675,"uses":1194,"awardedCount":1151}},"airdrop_multiple":{"properties":{"extraStat1":0,"uses":0,"awardedCount":0}},"directional_uav":{"properties":{"extraStat1":13,"uses":2,"awardedCount":1}}}},"accoladeData":{"properties":{"classChanges":138,"highestAvgAltitude":225,"killsFromBehind":203,"lmgDeaths":78,"riotShieldDamageAbsorbed":5,"flashbangHits":24,"meleeKills":34,"tagsLargestBank":0,"shotgunKills":109,"sniperDeaths":99,"timeProne":80,"killstreakWhitePhosphorousKillsAssists":1,"shortestLife":80,"deathsFromBehind":112,"higherRankedKills":181,"mostAssists":142,"leastKills":55,"tagsDenied":0,"killstreakWheelsonKills":0,"sniperHeadshots":41,"killstreakJuggernautKills":0,"smokesUsed":15,"avengerKills":129,"decoyHits":6,"killstreakCarePackageUsed":0,"molotovKills":15,"gasHits":0,"comebackKills":77,"lmgHeadshots":49,"smgDeaths":96,"carrierKills":0,"deployableCoverUsed":18,"thermiteKills":2,"arKills":137,"c4Kills":0,"suicides":47,"clutch":4,"survivorKills":0,"killstreakGunshipKills":2,"timeSpentAsPassenger":3,"returns":0,"smgHeadshots":169,"launcherDeaths":3,"oneShotOneKills":100,"ammoBoxUsed":1,"spawnSelectSquad":1,"weaponPickups":128,"pointBlankKills":200,"tagsCaptured":0,"killstreakGroundKills":0,"distanceTraveledInVehicle":2,"longestLife":139,"stunHits":56,"spawnSelectFlag":0,"shotgunHeadshots":92,"bombDefused":5,"snapshotHits":110,"noKillsWithDeath":3,"killstreakAUAVAssists":2,"killstreakPersonalUAVKills":13,"tacticalInsertionSpawns":63,"launcherKills":2,"spawnSelectVehicle":2,"mostKillsLeastDeaths":62,"mostKills":201,"defends":34,"timeSpentAsDriver":1,"bombDetonated":2,"arHeadshots":123,"timeOnPoint":0,"lmgKills":59,"killstreakUAVAssists":179,"carepackagesCaptured":24,"mostKillsLongestStreak":133,"killstreakCruiseMissileKills":6,"longestStreak":221,"destroyedKillstreaks":18,"hipfireKills":192,"stimDamageHealed":137,"skippedKillcams":76,"leastAssists":198,"mostMultikills":207,"highestRankedKills":179,"killstreakAirstrikeKills":34,"distanceTravelled":114,"killstreakKills":119,"semtexKills":6,"penetrationKills":128,"explosionsSurvived":104,"highestMultikill":241,"arDeaths":78,"longshotKills":231,"proximityMineKills":126,"tagsMegaBanked":0,"mostKillsMostHeadshots":95,"firstInfected":1,"killstreakCUAVAssists":3,"throwingKnifeKills":3,"executionKills":1,"lastSurvivor":0,"reconDroneMarks":0,"deadSilenceKills":58,"revengeKills":164,"infectedKills":1,"killEnemyTeam":186,"sniperKills":63,"killstreakCluserStrikeKills":7,"meleeDeaths":57,"timeWatchingKillcams":27,"killstreakTankKills":0,"noKillNoDeath":5,"shotgunDeaths":87,"killstreakChopperGunnerKills":67,"shotsFired":120,"stoppingPowerKills":3,"pistolPeaths":29,"killstreakShieldTurretKills":0,"timeCrouched":39,"noDeathsFromBehind":855,"bombPlanted":4,"setbacks":0,"smgKills":187,"claymoreKills":66,"kills10NoDeaths":1,"pistolHeadshots":20,"killstreakVTOLJetKills":105,"headshots":219,"mostDeaths":68,"adsKills":153,"empDroneHits":0,"defenderKills":157,"launcherHeadshots":2,"timesSelectedAsSquadLeader":2,"killstreakAirKills":124,"assaults":1,"fragKills":19,"killstreakEmergencyAirdropUsed":0,"captures":16,"killstreakChopperSupportKills":1,"spawnSelectBase":0,"noKill10Deaths":0,"leastDeaths":181,"killstreakSentryGunKills":0,"longestTimeSpentOnWeapon":0,"lowerRankedKills":171,"trophySystemHits":6,"clutchRevives":0,"lowestAvgAltitude":55,"pickups":0,"pistolKills":47,"reloads":134}}},"weekly":{"all":{"properties":null},"mode":{},"map":{}},"engagement":null}

Comment: Please don't post the whole response. A sample would be fine.

Comment: That is JSON formatted data. You need to parse it somehow, or instead use the `response.json()` method

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON response with `response.json()`, then access by key:

```
data = response.json()
kd_ratio = data['lifetime']['all']['properties']['kdRatio']
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a question about this though. So is each of those another dictionary inside of a dictionary?

Comment: That's exactly what you get when parsing that JSON, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can take the JSON response instead of a text response.

```
import requests as rq

header = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "call-of-duty-modern-warfare.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "0beff1d7acmsh29065741543208dp152ecbjsnb56e8654cc77"
    }


response = rq.get('https://call-of-duty-modern- 
warfare.p.rapidapi.com/multiplayer/%25C7%259Ep%25C3%25ABx%25231878/battle', headers=header)

print(response)

print(response.json()['lifetime']['all']['properties']['kdRatio'])
```

For better understanding:

```
data = response.json()
print(data.keys()) # will print all the keys
print(type(data['all'])) # checked the type.
# since it is dict
print(data['all'].keys())
print(data['all']['properties'])
print(data['all']['properties'].keys())
print(data['all']['properties']['kdRatio'])
```

Try this in ipython you will get more idea about json data

Comment: That second part there is awesome because it gives me a visual representation of how it goes through the dict, thanks.

Comment: Yes. I hope it helps you in understanding the concept.